# vb.net check the value of each column for only the 1st row datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatables

I want to check the first row only of a data table.  I want to verify that the right name is in the right column.  The first row has header name and they have to be in the right order. for example I want to check the first row and the first column to check that it has "First Name"

If I do the following it give me the right column data but it gives me the 2nd row not the first.  I don't get it since I am asking for row 0 and col 0.

```
Dim ExcelData As DataTable

field = ExcelData.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
```

(actually I will  want to do a IF to check this column.   first wanted to see what value is there before I code it all )

Comment: Do you want to check the column names or the rows? Cause you seem to mention that the table has headers, which would typically be stored under [`DataTable.Columns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: Are you talking about the actual data, or the column name?

Comment: Probably what you're after is `YourDataTable.Columns(0).ColumnName `.

Comment: I just got it working.  I messed with this all day yesterday and decided to ask. You're right Ahmed. That is what I just tried and it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much to all.